# Quotient groups and isomorphisms, example

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am wondering whether it is possible or not thata: 
$G \cong H$, $G_0 \cong H_0$ but $G/G_0 \not\cong H/H_0 $. In fact I found tahat as exercise asking to find such example but I can not find any. What is more important I can not understand how can it be possible. I thought isomorphisc groups are in fact thesame object with maby different names so I would be grateful also for some comment connected with that doubt.

Comment: It can even be done with $G=H$, and it has been, on this website, previously. Have a look to see if you can find it.

Comment: I think it might be better to mark as a duplicate of the question without the finiteness restriction, which changes the flavour of the answers a bit. I also hadn't seen this question before so didn't realize it was (or was likely to be) a duplicate until after answering. I'm inclined to leave my answer here because it has some general statements which don't seem to appear in answers to the duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

A hint to help you work out the counterexample - all (non-trivial) subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Conceptually, the problem is that while $G_0$ and $H_0$ might be isomorphic, they needn't sit inside $G$ and $H$ in the same way (by which I mean that maybe no isomorphism between $G$ and $H$ restricts to an isomorphism between $G_0$ and $H_0$). In the case that $f\colon G\to H$ is an isomorphism, and $H_0=f(G_0)$, you do get $G/G_0\cong H/H_0$, but in general the two isomorphisms needn't be related in this way.